# How can I make this subdivision deformation better/more consistent?

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, topology

I'm modelling something, and I've hit a snag. I wanted to use the subdivision modifier to get nice curves and some extra geometry, so that I could perhaps sculpt on it:

[image]

The issue is that the two raised projections with the gap between them don't properly flow with the shape of the model when subdivision is active:

[image]

I think the issue might be this pole, but I don't know how I'd go about getting this shape without it:

[image]

I noticed that I could add a bevel to that edge too, and while it gets rid of the distortion, I then lose the nice curve I wanted, and am left with an obvious unsightly crease:

[image]

I would very appreciative of any guidance someone could offer me!

Edit: included .blend. May look a little different to pictures, I was fiddling with it while trying to figure it out.

**Answer Edit:** Thanks for the answers! I tried out both methods and they both look good, although vklidu's creasing method does have the drawback of leaving that creased edge, even with a transitional quad. Moonboots' topology guide was helpful, and made me realise the shape needed more support loops. I guess next time I won't just leave it up the bevel modifier + subdiv.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably better to share your blend ... First image seems to have double faces or normal twists ... Another you can't use Bevel for a reason you spotted, you should limit the angle ... Did you use crease on some edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this topology:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help; I've updated the question with images showing the results of following both answers.

Answer (score 2):

With *Subdivision Surface* modifier and *Crease* you can get this ...

[image]

If sharp edge botter you, you would have to create a quad to help interpolate critical place ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help; I've updated the question with images showing the results of following both answers.